# HuggingFace datasets - how do I restart from a shard?

Tags: python, sharding, huggingface-datasets

Say I have a HuggingFace dataset `ds` which is big. Now assume I have a processing function `fn` that I want to apply to each element in the dataset. I want to call `fn` using `map` the following way in a `script.py`:

```py
def main():
    ...
    ds = ds.map(fn, **kwargs)
```

Now, say after processing for example a 100 rows the Python process started by running `python script.py` shuts down.

My question is the following - how do I write the `map` function in such a way that when I restart `script.py` it will restart the processing from the rows that come after the 100 rows it has already processed (i.e. don't rerun `fn` on the 100 rows it has already run on)?

I know that datasets have a `shard` method that can be used to write intermediate rows to disk, but how do I use this functionality to restart my process and not have to wait for `fn` to be run on rows it has already been run on?